# detail view that change color

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, detailsview

i have one detail view one for three different table i need to change some value (background image. color of tile) in base with table come from or set the color in the xml, anyone can help me?

that's the code that populate the detail view

```
//Definizione Foto
NSString *photo = mieRicette.foto;
foto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photo];


//Definizione Foto Orizzontale
NSString *photoOrizz = mieRicette.foto;
fotoOrizz.image = [UIImage imageNamed:photoOrizz];



//definizione Nome Orizzontale
nomeOrizz.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"populaire" size:37.5];
nomeOrizz.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
nomeOrizz.text=mieRicette.nome;


//definizione Dose
dose.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"populaire" size:25];
dose.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
dose.text=mieRicette.dose;


//definizione Nome e suo colore
nome.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LegacySerifLT-MediumItalic" size:25];
nome.text = mieRicette.nome;
nome.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f/255.0f green:70.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];


//definizione Tempo
tempo.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"populaire" size:25];
tempo.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55.0f/255.0f green:70.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
tempo.text=mieRicette.tempo;


//definizione Background
NSString *bck = mieRicette.bck;
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:bck];
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: my situation is three tableview and one detail view.

i need change background in detail view in base of the table that i come from.

sorry for my bad speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step1. set tag for each tableview, like tag 0,1,2

step2. create one uiimage instance in detailedviewcontroller then synthezise it

step3. before pushing the detailed viewcontroller, set the image of the detailedview controller based on the tableview

Comment: So easy and so hard for me... but not now after your explanation i WIN!!! thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can set background of your detail view before pushing your detail view controller.

Comment: Maybe here?

RicetteDetailViewController *ricetteDetailViewController = [[RicetteDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RicetteDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
 ricetteDetailViewController.mieRicette=[table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 self.navigationItem.title=[[table objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] nome];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:ricetteDetailViewController animated:YES];

    }